# Undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_pull_sample'

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Have the following problem with gstreamer application compilation. I was trying to code for retrieveing the framebuffer from GStreamer pipeline using following code.

```
char* pullImage(int* outlen, GstElement* sink)
{
    // Will block until sample is ready. In our case "sample" is encoded picture.

    GstAppSink *appsink = GST_APP_SINK(sink);
    if (!appsink) {
        printf("appsink is NULL\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    GstSample* sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);

    if(sample == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "gst_app_sink_pull_sample returned null\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Actual compressed image is stored inside GstSample.
    GstBuffer* buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);
    GstMapInfo map;
    gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

    // Allocate appropriate buffer to store compressed image
    char* pRet = new char[map.size];
    // Copy image
    memmove(pRet, map.data, map.size);

    gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);
    gst_sample_unref (sample);

    // Inform caller of image size
    *outlen = map.size;

    return pRet;
}
```

Then the following error occurs

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='--sysroot=/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux' '-march=armv8-a' '-mcpu=cortex-a53' '-std=c11' '-D' 'UCEXCONDATA_EXPORTS' '-D' '_GNU_SOURCE' '-I' '/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include' '-I' '/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0' '-I' '/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/glib-2.0' '-I' '/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include' '-I' '/home/xxx/workspace/codeTester/src' '-I' '/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/c++/7.3.0' '-I' '/home/xxx/LibPackages/arm-gsoap-2.8/gsoap/plugin' '-I' '/home/xxx/LibPackages/arm-gsoap-2.8/gsoap' '-I' '/home/xxx/LibPackages/arm-gsoap-2.8/gsoap/import' '-I' '/home/xxx/workspace/bwc-app/src/MsgProtocol/WSDD/gen' '-O0' '-Wall' '-c' '-fpermissive' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-fPIC' '-pthread' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.d' '-MT' '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o' '-o' '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
Building target: codeTester
Invoking: GCC C++ Cross-Linker
aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a  -mcpu=cortex-a53 --sysroot=/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux -L/usr/local/aarch64-linux/lib -L"/home/xxx/imx/QRCodeTest/library" -L/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib -L"/home/xxx/workspace/libwsdd" -pthread  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  ./src/utility/readpng.o  ./src/TestLoopShotWithBuffer.o  ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o   -ldl -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstrtspserver-1.0 -lpng -lstdc++ -lcodeTest -o  "codeTester"
./src/TestLoopShotWithBuffer.o: In function `pullImageBuffer(int*, _GstElement*)':
TestLoopShotWithBuffer.cpp:(.text+0x15c44): undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_get_type'
TestLoopShotWithBuffer.cpp:(.text+0x15c7c): undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_pull_sample'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:47: recipe for target 'codeTester' failed
make: *** [codeTester] Error 1
```

It seems to me as linker problem. I have searched around and found that the particular library gstreamer-app-1.0 has to be added. I subsequently add it to Eclipse. C++ Builder Settings/Libraries as one of the library required (found in gstreamer lib/pkconfig/). However when I tried to compile for the project

```
Building target: codeTester
Invoking: GCC C++ Cross-Linker
aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a  -mcpu=cortex-a53 --sysroot=/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux -L/usr/local/aarch64-linux/lib -L"/home/xxx/workspace/codeTester/library" -L/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/lib -L"/home/xxx/bwc-workspace/libwsdd" -pthread  -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  ./src/utility/readpng.o  ./src/TestLoopShotWithBuffer.o  ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.o   -ldl -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstrtspserver-1.0 -lgstreamer-app-1.0 -lpng -lstdc++ -lnsl -lm   -lcode -o  "codeTester"
/opt/imx/4.14-sumo/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/aarch64-poky-linux/gcc/aarch64-poky-linux/7.3.0/real-ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-app-1.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:47: recipe for target 'codeTester' failed
make: *** [codeTester] Error 1
```

I wonder what is wrong this time?

Regards

Comment: looks like gstreamer-app-1.0 isn't in any of the -L directories included in your build command. maybe you can find it and add its directory

Comment: @Ruizihm thanks for answering... i found the library to be actually under another name as it was supposed to be linked by pkconfig...the file i am pointing to happens to be the *.pc file... thus cause the error

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was solved by adding `gstapp-1.0` to the `target_link_libraries` in `CMakeLists.txt`